# Translate css problemas IOS

Tags: css, css3

Hola tengo un problema pienso que es con la propiedad de translate de css no me la detecta en equipos apple(iphone,ipad)

En la siguiente imagen explico mas a detalle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El texto mas chico y el boton principalmente estan abajo y cuando le picas a la imagen lo que tiene que pasar es que se suben haciendo la propiedad de translate funciona muy bien en pc,mac y en android pero en lo que son los dispositivos con IOS no hace nada

Pongo el codigo del css de esta imagen

```
.example-17 .wrapper {
background: url(img/testimonios/22.1.png) center/cover no-repeat;
}
.example-17 .wrapper:hover .menu-content span {
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -10px);
        transform: translate(-50%, -10px);
opacity: 1;
}
.example-17 .header {
color: #fff;
padding: 1em;
}
.example-17 .header::before, .example-17 .header::after {
content: '';
display: table;
}
.example-17 .header::after {
clear: both;
}
.example-17 .header .date {
float: left;
font-size: 12px;
}
.example-17 .menu-content {
float: right;
}
.example-17 .menu-content li {
margin: 0 5px;
position: relative;
}
.example-17 .menu-content span {
transition: all 0.3s;
opacity: 0;
}
.example-17 .data {
color: #fff;
-webkit-transform: translateY(calc(70px + 4em));
        transform: translateY(calc(70px + 4em));
}
.example-17 .title a {
color: #fff;
}
.example-17 .button {
display: block;
width: 100px;
margin: 2em auto 1em;
text-align: center;
font-size: 12px;
color: #fff;
line-height: 1;
position: relative;
font-weight: 700;
}
.example-17 .button::after {
content: '\2192';
opacity: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: -1000;
right: 0;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
        transform: translate(0, -50%);
transition: all 0.3s;
}
.example-17 .button:hover::after {
-webkit-transform: translate(5px, -50%);
        transform: translate(5px, -50%);
opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: En principio `transition` y `translate` funcionan en iOS. Es posible que el problema sea el `:hover` ya que sin ratón no puede hacerse aunque me extraña que funcione en android. Si es ese el problema tendrias que añadir la animación al pulsar el botón con javascript

Comment: Hola @LuisUribe, por favor añade también el HTML relacionado para que podamos ver el  problema directamente en la pregunta. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro tenga una duda no se si me la puedas aclarar en los equipos ios no funcional los enlaces osea un enlace general no funciona,pero solo con esa pagina con las demas si funcionan bien.

Comment: @LuisUribe sin ver el código no sabría decir